# embed jpgraph into with other php

Tags: php, jquery, html, mysql, jpgraph

I have a php page that is dependent on the previous page. Depending on the type of customer i click on so will i see their information on the next page. I now have a problem that I must have the graph embeded into the php page to retrieve SQL data just for that customer. Because if I have the graph on a separate PHP page it doesnt know which customer I click on to display their statistic.

How do i embed jpgraph into with other php?

PHP

```html
<?php

// Check connection
if (mysqli_connect_errno())
{
echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
}

$result = mysqli_query($mysqli,"SELECT rid, pid, firstname, lastname, email FROM temp_members_db WHERE pid='$pid1' ");

echo "<table><tr><th>Namn</th><th>E-mail</th><th>Resultat</th><th>Ta bort kandidat</th></tr>";
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
{

$count= "SELECT COUNT(qid) AS 'Total' FROM result WHERE rid=".$row['rid']."";
$result01 = mysqli_query($mysqli, $count); 
$resultArr01 = mysqli_fetch_array($result01);
$total= $resultArr01[0]*10;

$pointsummary= "SELECT SUM(points) AS 'Summary' FROM result WHERE rid=".$row['rid']."";
$result02 = mysqli_query($mysqli, $pointsummary);
$resultArr02 = mysqli_fetch_array($result02);

$sum= $resultArr02[0];

$result00 = ($total != 0 ? round($sum/$total*100) : 0);
  
 

    
    $color = "#000000";

if (($result00 >= 1) && ($result00 <= 30))
   $color = "#FF0000";
else if (($result00 > 30) && ($result00 <= 60))
   $color = "#FF9900";
else if (($result00 > 60) && ($result00 <= 100))
   $color = "#07d407";

echo "<tr><td><strong>
<form action='/devlopment/graph.php' method='GET'>
 <input type='hidden' name='rid' value='".$row['rid']."'>
 <input type='hidden' name='firstname' value='".$row['firstname']."'> 
<input type='submit' class='resname' name='submit' value='".$row['firstname']." ".$row['lastname']."'>

 </form>
 </strong></td> 
 <td>".$row['email']."</td> 
 <td><strong><span style=\"color: $color\">".$result00."</span>%</strong></td>   
 
 <form action='deleterespondent2.php' method='post'>
 <input type='hidden' name='rid' value='".$row['rid']."'> 
<td> <input type='submit' class='mydel' value='Radera' onclick=\"return confirm('Vill du verkligen radera kandidaten? \\n\\nObservera att kandidatens eventuellt besvarade frågor och resultat raderas också!')\">
 </form>
</td></tr>";

}
echo "</table>";
mysqli_close($mysqli);
?>
```

graph

```html
<?php 
require_once('jpgraph/jpgraph.php');  
require_once('jpgraph/jpgraph_line.php');  
require_once('jpgraph/jpgraph_bar.php'); 
session_start();
$val = (isset($_GET['rid']))  ? 
    "{$_GET['rid']}" : '';  
 
$x_axis = array();  
$y_axis = array();  
$i      = 0;  
$con    = mysqli_connect("root", "g", "f", "d");  
// Check connection  
if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {  
    echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();  
}  
$result = mysqli_query($con, "SELECT * FROM result WHERE rid=$val");  
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {  
    $x_axis[$i] = $row["qid"];
    $y_axis[$i] = $row["points"];
    $i++;  
}  


mysqli_close($con);  
$width  = 600;  
$height = 200;  
$graph  = new Graph($width, $height);  
$graph->SetScale('textint');  
$graph->title->Set('My Example');  
$graph->xaxis->title->Set('(Fråga)');  
$graph->xaxis->SetTickLabels($x_axis);  
$graph->yaxis->title->Set('(Poäng)');  
$barplot = new BarPlot($y_axis);  
$graph->Add($barplot);  
$graph->Stroke();
?>
```

Comment: let's say your graph file filename is `graph.php` and your other php file filename is `file.php` , so have you tried including your graph file in your other `php` file? like in your `file.php` you add this line: `include 'graph.php';`. in that case you do not need to use another `mysqli` connection if it's connecting to same `db`

Answer (score 0):

This may be late but just in case or for someone else here, you really dont need to place the JGraph on the same page. However embedding would be correct. Based on the above, you could do this:

```php
//graphshow.php
<?php 
require_once('jpgraph/jpgraph.php');  
require_once('jpgraph/jpgraph_line.php');  
require_once('jpgraph/jpgraph_bar.php');

if (isset($_GET['axes'])) {
    $axes = explode("^^", $_GET['axes']);
    $x_axis = $axes[0];
    $y_axis = $axes[1];
}

$width = 600;  
$height = 200;  
$graph = new Graph($width, $height);  
$graph->SetScale('textint');  
$graph->title->Set('My Example');  
$graph->xaxis->title->Set('(Fråga)');  
$graph->xaxis->SetTickLabels($x_axis);  
$graph->yaxis->title->Set('(Poäng)');  
$barplot = new BarPlot($y_axis);  
$graph->Add($barplot);  
$graph->Stroke();
?>
```

And then in your main php, where you need the graph to appear:

```php
<?php
session_start();
$val = (isset($_GET['rid'])) ? "{$_GET['rid']}" : '';  
$x_axis = array();  
$y_axis = array();  
$i = 0;  
$con = mysqli_connect("root", "g", "f", "d");  
// Check connection  
if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {  
    echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();  
}  
$result = mysqli_query($con, "SELECT * FROM result WHERE rid=$val");  

while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {  
    $x_axis[$i] = $row["qid"];
    $y_axis[$i] = $row["points"];
    $i++;  
}
$xy = $x_axis."^^".y_axis; 
?>

<div>
    <embed src="graphshow.php?axes=<?php echo $xy; ?>" height=80em; width=160em;> </embed>
</div>
```